# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed laravel 6

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, mariadb, laravel-6

I have 2 tables and when I try to migrate return to me this error:

> General error: 1005 Can't create table `usee_anbari`.`#sql-473_21177` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `companies` add constraint `companies_access_id_foreign` foreign key (`access_id`) references `accesses` (`id`) on delete cascade)

this is my tables:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('address');
        $table->string('tel1');
        $table->string('tel2');
        $table->integer('owner');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('access_id');
        $table->string('depot_number')->default(2);
        $table->timestamps();


        $table->foreign('access_id')->references('id')->on('accesses')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

and another one :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('accesses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('type');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

what I miss?

Comment: Is that the order in which your tables are created? Table `accesses` needs to exist before you can reference it

Comment: @kerbholz in my localhost it's done successfully but in the server just return me this error and I get the error when I want to create  companies table

Comment: well one is bigIncrements and the other one is unsignedBigInteger, instead you have to use bigInteger

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia `bigIncrements` is `unsignedBigInteger`

Answer (score 0):

In your `database/migrations` folder, sort by name. Then make sure `create_accesses_table` is before `create_companies_table`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and I'm here describing how to I have solved it.

You have to use `unsignedBigInteger` instead of `unsignedInteger`. See the below code:

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable(); // Changed here
    $table->string('ip_address')->nullable();
    $table->string('email')->nullable();
    $table->text('message')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('user_id')
    ->references('id')->on('users')
    ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Where you will use `foreign` there use the `unsignedBigInteger` (if have id). If still not clear, please put a comment.